# Should question on Jewish beliefs be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Should [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/were-the-jews-expecting-god-incarnate) about Jewish beliefs be closed for the reasons given in [this meta post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594/closed-can-atheists-be-moral) explaining a moderator's reason for closing a question about atheism and [this other meta post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/old-new-testament-jewish-culture-on-or-off-topic) that explains another moderator's reason for closing a question on Judaism?

If not, what's the difference?

I tried to vote to close it as off topic, but the open bounty is preventing me from doing that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Old/New Testament Jewish culture: On or Off topic?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/291/old-new-testament-jewish-culture-on-or-off-topic)

Answer (score 4):

Questions about Jewish beliefs are on-topic if they relate to Old testament times, or to New testament times such that they impact Christian teaching, or provide context to the Gospels or other early Christian accounts. In the example given the question in clearly on-topic because it can help with the understanding of the Biblical accounts, the Jews' reaction to Jesus' Messianic claims, and generally with the culture of the times.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you linked regarding "What were the Jews expecting..." is reasonably on that edge between Christian teachings and the teachings of Judaism.

The question is really about the birth of Christianity. In other words, what did "Jews-following-Jesus" believe versus "Jews-who-didn't-believe" and where, exactly, did they disagree and split? It's exactly that moment where Jewish and Christian doctrine last overlap then diverge. I see that as perfectly on topic.

In a much broader sense, if the question was strictly asking about Jewish teachings — with no reasonable connection to the subject of "Christianity" — I would probably close it. As a site tightly scoped around the subject of Christianity, it's out of scope to start taking about matters of purely Jewish teachings, unless it has a reasonable connection to what you discuss here.

When it comes to Jewish (or any other religion's) teaching, there may be a strong *correlation* of what you happen to have extra-curricular knowledge of, but that's is entirely different than what is on topic for *this* site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to tell anyone what to do, but I think that [Closed - Can Atheists be moral?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594/closed-can-atheists-be-moral) ought to be rescinded.

If you don't agree with it, join me and downvote it.

I ask the question here, mainly because I think Christians can have at least as good an understanding of Jewish culture around the time of Christ. And why shouldn't they?  It's not like Christianity didn't come directly out of Judaism.

Now regarding atheism, I'd tend to agree with anyone who considers it off topic IF atheism were actually a religion.  It has some elements of religion, except no one who is in it considers it a religion.

Comment: I believe that your post (linked in the original question) is on topic ([see my answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/600/should-question-on-jewish-beliefs-be-closed/610#610)). You completely mischaracterized my meta post in your straw man argument. Asking what Jews believed during the arrival of Jesus is certainly a matter of doctrine; a question that can be easily answered objectively. It's not a "pick on the other guy" value judgement that I am trying to dissuade for the good of the community in my meta post

Comment: @robert any question of morality can be answered objectively on this site because we have recourse to the Natural Moral Law. `No member of the faithful could possibly deny that the Church is competent in her magisterium to interpret the natural moral law.` (Humanae Vitae, Article 4).

Comment: I'm not questioning your "moral competency" to talk about your issues anywhere else. I am talking about forgoing these discussions on *this* site to keep the scope tightly-defined in the larger interest of building a great canon of Christian knowledge. Certainly you would admit that other folks have the "right" to question your beliefs, but I explicitly ask THEM to keep it out of here, simply for reasons of good community building. If you want to open this site to *anything* you feel qualified to discuss on that basis alone, this will become fodder to endless debate which will end this site.